# How do I pull and rebase from remote to master and rebase from master to my feature branch in one shot?

Tags: git

I have a feature branch that I'm trying to keep updated with remote master. I also want to keep my local master updated too. I'm not working on master but it's good to keep it updated.

This is my work flow

```
(feature_branch)> git checkout master
(master)> git pull --rebase
(master)> git checkout feature_branch
(feature_branch)> git rebase master
```

Can I do it with less commands?

Comment: If you're not working on `master`, why are you rebasing your local copy of it on top of the remote copy?  You want to just pull changes into your local copy, so you don't need the `--rebase` flag in this case.

Comment: `--rebase` is unnecessary, you are right. That's just a habit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Nathan suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17624567/456814), you can make a Git alias to combine a bunch of commands into one:

```
$ git config --global alias.sync \
"!git fetch <remote> master:master && git rebase master"

# With the feature branch checked out
$ git sync
```

This sets up an alias `sync` that first updates your local `master` from the remote `master`, using a fast-forward only merge.  Then it rebases your current branch (make sure it's the `feature_branch`) on top of your local `master`.

The advantage of using `git fetch master:master` is that it doesn't require you to check out your `master` branch before updating it from the remote repo.  This is how the [Git fetch docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) explains how the syntax works:

> The format of a `<refspec>` parameter is an optional plus `+`, followed by the source ref `<src>`, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref `<dst>`.
>
> The remote ref that matches `<src>` is fetched, and if `<dst>` is not empty string, the local ref that matches it is fast-forwarded using `<src>`. If the optional plus `+` is used, the local ref is updated even if it does not result in a fast-forward update.

So, in the example I give, `git fetch master:master` says to fetch `master` from the remote repo as `<src>`, and since `<dst>` is non-empty (it's the right hand side, local `master`), Git attempts to fast-forward merge `<dst>` using `<src>`.

Comment: As an interesting aside, the only reason I found out about the refspec trick with `git fetch` was because I was using Git auto-completion in bash, and I happened to press tab one too many times to fetch `master` and it auto-completed as `git fetch origin master:master`. I was intrigued, so I looked it up in the Git docs, and now I'm even more productive in Git than I used to be!

Answer (score 1):

If your master is not ahead of origin/master, then you can do it with one less command, though it is admittedly a bit hacky:

```
git fetch
git push . origin/master:master
git rebase master
```

If your master is ahead of origin/master then I don't know of any faster way to do it than what you're doing. You could, of course, make an alias or shell function for it.

EDIT: [Cupcake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17627452/788472) is definitely the best solution, and now I know that a refspec in a fetch initiates a ff merge!

Answer (score 1):

```
(master)> git checkout feature_branch
(feature_branch)> git rebase master
```

may be combined into one command:

```
(master)> git rebase master feature_branch
(feature_branch)>
```

And you may get rid of `--rebase` in the `git pull` call if you configure

```
rebase = true
```

for the master branch in .git/config.